# Django: What do I pass in as self in the view.py if I am using a function from model.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I created a simple Django view that is suppose to print out the list of names field from my model. I created a function inside my User model to query the names, and append it to a list, and return that. I want to call this function inside my view class, and pass that list as a context so I can use it inside my template.

Below is my current code. I am not sure what self is suppose to be when I am trying to call it in views.py. When I try passing in my model name, which is User, it did not work. So what exactly is self suppose to be in the views.py? Thanks in advance:D

User models.py

```
def query_choice(self,query_choice):
    users_first_name = self.objects.values_list(query_choice)
    names = []
    for u in users_first_name:
        names.append(u)
    return names
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    users_first_name = User.query_name(*self*,'first_name')
    template = loader.get_template('registration/home.html')
    context = {
        'output': users_first_name,
    }
    #return HttpResponse(output)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

Comment: Note: you can pass in the flat=true,  parameter to values_list then your function becomes one line long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `query_choice` as a class method using [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator in your model:

```
@classmethod
def query_choice(cls, query_choice):
    return cls.objects.values_list(query_choice, flat=True)
```

Then you can call it like below:

```
names = User.query_choice("first_name")
```

By they way, you can use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to save yourself the mess of loading template, then rendering it etc:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def login(request):
    names = User.query_choice("first_name")
    return render(request, "registration/home.html", {"output": names})
```